# Python error with literals and lists in loguru: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, operands, loguru

Working with loguru in order to write a list back to the configuration file, and received the dreaded `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'` error. I know the error came from attempting to combine a literal and a list. I attempted to break down the line by using a variable to represent the literal, and this only generated the same error.

#### Block of code with problematic line:

```py
def update_config(config: dict):
    """
    Update exisitng configuration file.

    Parameters
    ----------
    config: dict
        Configuraiton to be written into config file.
    """
    config["ids_to_retry"] = list(set(config["ids_to_retry"] + FAILED_IDS))
    with open("config.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
        yaml.dump(config, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
    logger.info("Updated last read message_id to config file")
```

#### Full error output:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                             
  File "/telegram-downloader-quackified/media_downloader.py", line 359, in <module>                                                               
    main()                                                                                                                                                     
  File "/telegram-downloader-quackified/media_downloader.py", line 343, in main                                                                   
    updated_config = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(                                                                                              
  File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete                                                                
    return future.result()                                                                                                                                     
  File "/telegram-downloader-quackified/media_downloader.py", line 324, in begin_import                                                           
    update_config(config)                                                                                                                                      
  File "/telegram-downloader-quackified/media_downloader.py", line 35, in update_config                                                           
    config["ids_to_retry"] = list(set(config["ids_to_retry"] + FAILED_IDS))
```

I know something needs to change in the phrase `list(set(config["ids_to_retry"] + FAILED_IDS))`, I just am not sure what.

---

#### Providing more info:

FAILED_IDS is a list generated when the script encounters an exception and cannot successfully complete the download. When this occurs the message id is stored in memory like so `FAILED_IDS.append(message.message_id)`. Then it is written to the configuration file with the following statement:

```py
if FAILED_IDS:
        logger.info(
            "Downloading of %d files failed. "
            "Failed message ids are added to config file.\n",
            len(set(FAILED_IDS)),
        )
    update_config(updated_config)
```

It's original value is:

```py
FAILED_IDS: list = []
```

Where "ids_to_retry" is more or less just a label used in the configuration file. It is just a literal string, and is the nonetype. The ends result is for the two to be written in the configuration file to resemble something like the following:

```py
ids_to_retry:
- 26125
- 2063
- 2065
- 2080
- 2081
- 22052
- 21029
- 553
- 554
- 555
- 2102
- 22074
```

I hope this clarifies the nature of the variables we are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for failure is `config["ids_to_retry"] = None` and you are trying to extend a Nonetype to a list. You can use something like

`config["ids_to_retry"] = list(set(config["ids_to_retry"] + FAILED_IDS)) if config["ids_to_retry"] else FAILED_IDS`

So if `config["ids_to_retry"]` is `None` it would take `config["ids_to_retry"] = FAILED_IDS`, Without trying to extending it.

Assumption made that `FAILED_IDS` is a list if not you can type cast it to a list.

Comment: It appears that your corrected statement places FAILED_IDS and "ids_to_retry" in an either/or arguement. I might be wrong about this, but I am trying it out regardless.

Comment: Actually it is something similar to the ternary operator, I am extending the list if ids_to_retry is not None.  If none using the FAILED_IDS

Comment: It is just tooting right along, scraping to all it's glory. Seems to have worked nicely. "The code is strong with this one..." Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed, script completed successfully.